# Web Scraper: Generate Excel sheet from JSON data extracted from a website using the library Axios, cheerio and Exceljs

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios, cheerio, exceljs

I want to generate the data in an excel sheet that i have extracted from a website in JSON format.

I have use this line of code to get the data in JSON format:
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {fs.writeFile('scraper.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err, data) => {if (err) {reject(err)} else resolve(data)})})

Can please anyone guide me the steps to generate the JSON data in an excel sheet?

```
  const Datas = () => {
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook()
workbook.creator = 'Test'
workbook.created = new Date()
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Interest Data')
worksheet.columns = [{ header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 20 }, { header: 'Number', key: 'Number', width: 32 }]

worksheet.addRows()
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  workbook.xlsx.writeFile('scraper.xlsx'), (err, data) => { => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else resolve(data)
  })
})
```

}

Comment: woud that be possible to share the code you tried?

Comment: Im trying to add the codes.